# How to find n occurences of an expression with boost spirit?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have this grammar passed to `phrase_parse()`

`double_[push_back(phoenix::ref(v), _1)] >> *(*blank >> double_[push_back(phoenix::ref(v), _1)])`

The second expression starting with `*(*blank`, finds out 0 or more occurrences of 
'double'. In my case I want to make sure it matches exactly 6 occurrences. Is it possible to do this in boost spirit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [repeat](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/repeat.html) directive. There's no need to use [semantic actions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/semantic_actions.html) either when parsing a list of numbers, all you need is the [`%`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/list.html) operator. In this case, since your numbers are separated by whitespace, you don't need to use that either, the skipper you pass to `phrase_parse` does the trick.

```
auto result = qi::phrase_parse(first, last,
                               qi::repeat(6)[qi::double_],
                               qi::space,
                               v);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83b6c584680c408e)

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

void parse(std::string const& s)
{
    auto first = s.cbegin(), last = s.cend();
    std::vector<double> v;

    auto result = qi::phrase_parse(first, last,
                                   qi::repeat(6)[qi::double_],
                                   qi::space,
                                   v);
    if(result) {
        if(first == last) {
            std::cout << "Success (complete)  : ";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Success (incomplete): ";
        }
        for(auto d : v) std::cout << d << ' ';
        std::cout << " Remaining: " << std::string{first, last} << '\n';

    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    parse("10 20   30 40 50       60      ");
    parse("10 20   30 40 50       60 70 80");
    parse("10 20   30 40");
}
```

Output:

```
Success (complete)  : 10 20 30 40 50 60  Remaining: 
Success (incomplete): 10 20 30 40 50 60  Remaining: 70 80
Failed
```

Comment: Is the list operator (`%' '`) really needed? Since you are using `qi::space` as a skipper it does nothing but if there were no skipper it would do the wrong thing.

Comment: @cv_and_he Thanks! I don't have a whole lot of experience with Spirit and had no idea you could do any list parsing without using `%`. Updated the answer.